# bash substring syntax as a means of disambiguating environment variable identifiers

Tags: bash

When bashing, I know that double quoting is sometimes necessary if an environment variable (EV) contains embedded spaces.  Example: `"$JACK"` rather than `$JACK`.  Sometimes it is recommended to use the syntax borrowed from substringing if the identifier of the EV is ambiguous.  Example, because the EV is not `$JACKA`, `$JACKAN`, nor `$JACKAND` we would use curly braces with no substring indices to write `${JACK}ANDJILL`.

It seems that double quotes can accomplish the same thing.  Example: `"$JACK"ANDJILL`

In fact if we do nothing but `echo` the following demonstrates equivalence.

```
#!/bin/bash
TEXAS="asdf asdf"
FLORIDA="qwer""$TEXAS""qwer" # use quotes
echo $FLORIDA

ALABAMA="qwer"${TEXAS}"qwer" # use substring without indices
echo $ALABAMA

ARIZONA="qwer""${TEXAS}""qwer" # use both
echo $ARIZONA

MAINE="qwer"$TEXAS"qwer" # use neither
echo $MAINE

NEVADA="qwer""$TEXAS"qwer # last bit not quoted
echo $NEVADA

IDAHO="qwer"${TEXAS}qwer # last bit not quoted
echo $IDAHO
```

The output:

```
    qwerasdf asdfqwer
    qwerasdf asdfqwer
    qwerasdf asdfqwer
    qwerasdf asdfqwer
    qwerasdf asdfqwer
    qwerasdf asdfqwer
```

Are there bash statements/constructs where the substring trick cannot be substituted with double quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substring has more function, as the name says it can be used to take a substring of a variable.
For example

```
var='123456789'
echo ${var:2:4}
```

Will output

> 3456

While using array you have to use substring for accessing array variables.
For example

```
a[0]=0
a[1]=1
a[2]=2
```

`echo $a` will print 0.
 `echo "$a[1]"` output 0[1]
So accessing array variable at location 1 as follows

```
echo ${a[1]}
```

This outputs 1

`echo "${a[@]}"` output all variable. ie 0 1 2
In these cases substring can't be repaced with ""